# Trying to get two buttons remained in the status column of a grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a couple of buttons under the Status column as per screenshot.

Here's my HTML code below( the picture)

[image]

```
<div class="table_heading_row">
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Leave Type
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Total Count
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 150px;">
        Start Date
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        End Date
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Status
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table_row 1">
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Sick Leave
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 150px;">
        2 Days
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        2.8.2013
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        3.8.2013
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Rejected
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table_row 2">
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Sick Leave
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 150px;">
        3 days
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        6.3.2014
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        8.3.2014
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Rejected
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table_row 3">
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        Annual Leave
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 150px;">
        13 days
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        6.3.2014
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
        8.3.2014
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px; display:inline-flex;">
        <div style="float:left; style=" background-color: green; width: 64px;">
            <input type="button" name="Approve" value="Approve">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;" style="background-color: red;width: 64px;"> 
            <input type="button" name="Reject" value="Reject">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Under the div class `table_row3` for the annual leave part row, I want to make to make the last column to include two buttons (with some CSS styling on) and I ended up have two green and red buttons stick next each other.  Whilst this is the closest resemblance to the picture below, I'm just not sure this is great approach...  I need another suggestion of a better way of handling this buttons sitting under the status columns with such margins or paddings.

Any ideas?

You can also check it live online.

http://cms.tmadev.com.au/staffleaveapproval.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, I put a little something together in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/e5Fwk/).

JS

```
$('#app').click(function(){
     $('#adstatus').html("<span id='stapp'>Approved</span>");
});
$('#deny').click(function(){
     $('#adstatus').html("<span id='stden'>Denied</span>");
});
```

You can click on either the Approved or Denied words and the html will change.

You can then add another function for clicking on the status to change it.

Comment: Thanks TimSPQR.  This could prove useful in determining the correct status change when clicking on them.  May help me in writing layout code after all!